# Usage of Waratek JVM

Tags: java, jvm, cloud, containers, paas

I recently read about Waratek company's implementation of the JVM, which allows up to 64 Java apps to be run on a single JVM, saving resources when exchanging data between apps etc.

I know this might be private to some companies, but among publicly available information,
does any PaaS company use Waratek JVM, or at least a JVM that utilises a similar concept? Or the benefits of this approach are outperformed by the widely used container paradigm?

Comment: This will probably be closed as primarily opinion based.

Comment: So, the only way to find out where this specific JVM is used is to guess?